# Word for group of noisy people

Tags: word-request

I was studying, and I heard noises coming from the other room. I went there, and found that they were just happy, laughing, joking and congratulating as somebody had been engaged.

Which word can I use to describe what was happening in other room?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Can you be more specific? In your title you ask for a word for the *group*, as if you want either a *collective noun* or an *adjective* like *noisy*. But in the body of your question you ask for a word which describes *what was happening*, which might be an adjective or a noun or a verb. Could you edit your question to give us a sample sentence, with a ____ where the word you want would go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know a single word that would replace "a group of noisy people". There's a whole bunch of adjectives that could describe that group of people - amongst [synonyms of **noisy**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/noisy?s=t) 
(bolding ones that would match the situations best),:

chattering, disorderly, ear-popping, ear-splitting, loudmouth, rackety, raising Cain, raising the roof, rambunctious, riotous, **rowdy**, screaming, **tumultous/tumultuous**, turned up, uproarious

and quite a few nouns to describe the situation - [synonyms of **ruckus**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/ruckus?s=ts)

disturbance, big scene, bother, brawl, **commotion**, disorder, disruption,  fray, fuss, **hubbub**, racket, stir, turmoil, upheaval, uproar

Comment: Although it is two words, a "cacophonous gaggle" comes to mind.  :)

Comment: "`Gaggle`" was the first word than sprang into my mind

Answer (score 4):

I think **loud crowd** can be a good term for it or a **loud room** or **loud people**. Surely as StoneyB said your question doesn't make it clear what you mean of "to describe what happening in other room"

Comment: I think you mean "surely", not "surly".  ("Surly" is an adjective meaning "ill-tempered".  If appropriate, it would be followed directly by the word it modifies, not separated from it by "as", and the modified word would not ordinarily be a name, but a more generic word, as a "surly individual".)  But I do like the sound of "loud crowd".

Comment: Thanks! Surely it was surely! I edited it. A mistake in typing.

Comment: I would avoid "loud crowd" just because of the rhyming, personally.

Answer (score 3):

They were a **raucous** group!

Not exactly a commonly used word these days, but I think most english speakers would still know what it means as it still gets used in writing fairly often.

You can have raucous crowds, a raucous party, raucous laughter, etc.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/raucous

Answer (score 2):

Gaggle - Group of noisy people

Comment: Welcoem aboard. I upvoted, since that it the first word that sprang to my mind, but it is usual to include a dictionary definition reference (and you might also mention geese ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to describe a noisy group of people, depending on the context of your thought. You might choose different words depending on whether or not they bother you, for instance.

1. If you **do not** find them annoying. these tend to have a positive connotation:

   - party
   - celebration
   - soiree
   - fete
   - *e.g. I would definitely rather be at that soiree than studying; how jovial!*
2. If you **do** find them annoying, these have a negative connotation:

   - cacophony
   - circus
   - sideshow
   - horde
   - clamor
   - mob
   - gaggle
   - racket
   - *e.g. May that spiteful, wretched horde be smote by mighty Thor so that I might read in peace...*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers, mob, gaggle, cacophony could be used,

if you are looking in context of people who gossip loudly, 
"Klatsch" is a germanic word, which could be used.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any references for klatsch being related to gossip?  I suspect most people, British at least, would simply associate "Klatch" with Discworld.

Comment: The word means gossip in german.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klatch is what I used to confirm my answer.

Comment: @Giridhur a word may exist in a dictionary but it does not mean that it is in common usage amongst ordinary people.

Answer (score -1):

Boisterous is the perfect word. It means loud, rowdy, energetic people. One definition found at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/boisterous) is:

> **boisterous** (*adj.*) Turbulent; rough and noisy; clamorous: applied to persons or their actions: as, *a boisterous man; boisterous merriment; a boisterous game*.